# LINQ to Entities error only after deploying to new IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, iis

I am working on a WebAPI site, it includes some login logic that has worked on a previous server, and on the development/localhost but does not work after deploying it to a new IIS server (previous server crashed, unrecoverable).

Configuration is now that the DB and the Web server are the same VM on a server so we don't have this bare metal problem again.  New server is 2012 R2 running latest IIS updates.  The login process or our our website worked fine but now we are getting this error:

```
Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities
```

The stack trace leads me to this code:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) return;

    using (var db = new PerformanceSecurityRoleContext())
    {
        var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var userEntry = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdSid.ToLower().Equals(user.Identity.Name.ToLower()));
        var roles = userEntry == null 
            ? FindRolesByGroups(db, User as WindowsPrincipal)
            : FindRolesByUser(db, userEntry);

        if(roles == null) return;
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity();
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
            ClaimsPrincipal.Current.AddIdentity(id);
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<Role> FindRolesByUser(PerformanceSecurityRoleContext db, User user)
{
    return db.UserRoles.Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(user.Id)).Select(x => x.Role);
}

private static IEnumerable<Role> FindRolesByGroups(PerformanceSecurityRoleContext db, WindowsPrincipal user)
{
    var groupList = (db.Groups.Select(g => new {g, name = new SecurityIdentifier(g.Name)})
        .Where(@t => user.IsInRole(@t.name))
        .Select(@t => @t.g)).ToList();

    var rolesList = new List<Role>();
    foreach (var g in groupList)
    {
        rolesList.AddRange(g.GroupRoles.Select(x => x.Role));
    }
    return rolesList.Distinct();
}
```

In particular, it seems to be this line:

```
var groupList = (db.Groups.Select(g => new {g, name = new SecurityIdentifier(g.Name)})
    .Where(@t => user.IsInRole(@t.name))
    .Select(@t => @t.g)).ToList();
```

Why does it work localhost and on the previous server but not now?  If I just got lucky before and I need to make concrete calls that is fine and I need to learn something but it seems to me a configuration issue.  I spent a few hours looking for the answer but I must be asking the wrong question.

Comment: It's telling you that in the deployed code, there is a class that represents some table that you are querying (my guess is that it's the `role` class) that does not have a constructor that takes zero arguments.

Comment: No, of course, it's the `SecurityIdentifier`class. give it an empty constructor and change the code to: `name = new SecurityIdentifier{ Name = g.Name}`

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen, the `SecurityIdentifier` class doesn't have a blank constructor and Name isn't a public property, do you mean I should override the class and add this as an initialization constructor?  I am fairly sure I can do that safely, if so thanks.  Doesn't explain why it used to work before we rebuilt the web server, any ideas?

Comment: Found the reason why we think the error didn't occur before: Old server the code never ran before because we were testing with our domain logins, which were authorized.  New security setup on the servers has local only logins for servers, hence no domain accounts.  Pretty funny really.  Still working on some of the authorization issues, but seems ok now.